# What is the most efficient way to determine if a point is in any number of boxes

Tags: c++, algorithm, processing-efficiency

I know how to check if a X,Y point is a single rectangular region, but say I have multiple regions that can potentially overlap ( the regions would have X,Y,Width,Height,Z-index ( or x1,y1,x2,y2 if that's easier -- I am not fussed on how I store that, if it's relevant )

Are there any efficient algorithms to determine if the point is inside one of the regions without having to iterate over every region.

I would prefer something without a long recalculation time when a region is added or removed, however that will be rarer then lookups.

Thank you!

Comment: Are these rectangles aligned with the x- and y-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store your regions into a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (or Octree if 3D). This would help you to reject most of the regions before getting into the real collision-test.

If you have multiple layers, simply have a quadtree per layer and use the relevant one according to the layer in which your point lies.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for -- somehow I totally missed those in my own research!

Answer (score 1):

[Volumetric kd-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree#Volumetric_objects)?